# How to dynamically specify Query String in Web API URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am new to c# and web api. I have a WebAPI controller with a Get method as follows:

```
 public class peopleController : ApiController
 {
     [HttpGet]
     public IHttpActionResult getAllPeople(string Name, string Age)
     {
        //Return something
     }
 }
```

My WebApiConfig is like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "getAllPeopleApi",
            routeTemplate: "people",
            defaults: new { controller = "people", action = "getAllPeople" }

        );
```

If I invoke my url like this : `http://localhost:xxx/people?Name=&Age=`. It working fine.

But when I invoke like all these: 
`http://localhost:xxx/people`,`http://localhost:xxx/people?Name=`,`http://localhost:xxx/people?Age=`

I got this error message:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:xxxx/......'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'people' that matches the request."}
```

I try to set my `routeTemplate: "people/{Name}/{Age}"`. Now when I run this web api `Error 404.0 Not Found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by explicitly set parameter `Name` and `Age` to `Null`.

```
public class peopleController : ApiController
 {
     [HttpGet]
     public IHttpActionResult getAllPeople(string Name = null, string Age=null)
     {
        //Return something
     }
 }
```

This will made the parameters as an optional parameters. Now you can invoke the controller with or without Query string parameter.

Comment: Since you have answered your own question, don’t forget to accept it as answer. Of course, there are some restrictions. Check it here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 0):

```
routeTemplate: "people/{Name}/{Age}"
```

This part is not a QueryString, this is a dynamic path.
That means that your path becomes `Domain/people/SomeName/SomeAge?QueryString=Whatever`

Comment: Thanks @Freek W. for clarification. For query string can I achieve as per my question ?

Comment: The QueryString is always the last part in the Url after the `?` indicator. You can call the querystring in the controller with `Request.QueryString["AttributeNameHere"]`. I'm not sure this is the answer to your question, please elaborate your question.

Comment: If I run my webApi like this `http://localhost:xxx/people?Name=&Age=` I get the the response. If I remove both or one of parameter `Name`, `Age`, like so `http://localhost:xxx/people` got error not No Http Resource was found. Is this clear for u ?

Comment: That is because just `domain/people` is not a route (it does not exist), the route is explicitly `domain/people/{Name}/{Age}` (this only exists), these two dynamic items need to be met in order for the request to find the page. Still not really clear on the question though, is it that you want to add the querystring to something within your controller or do you want to dynamically add the values to your route? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Okay, my question how can I dynamically specify my query string in URL. For now when do like this `http://localhost:xxx/people?Name=&Age=` OK. When do like these 3 `http://localhost:xxx/people,http://localhost:xxx/people?Name=,http://localhost:xxx/people?Age=` not ok. Is this clear u up ?

Comment: Well you could replace `url: "/people/{Name}/{Age}"`with `url: "/people"` and just send what ever data in the QueryString like this: `Domain/people?Name=Freek&Age=23`, You can also send do `Domain/people?Name=Freek`, and use the controller to send the webpage based on the request (querystring information).

Comment: Yes, this is my problem rn. I can only send like `Domain/people?Name=Freek&Age=23` but cannot like this `Domain/people?Name=Freek` .I stated clearly in my question about my `controller` and `route` in `WebApiconfig`. Do I need to set something, somewhere ?

Comment: You what i'm taking from this is that you want to keep `people/{Name}/{Age}` in tact? You could try to use this in your `defaults`: `{ Name = RouteParameter.Optional, Age =  RouteParameter.Optional }`. Moreover here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional-uri-parameters-and-default-values

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I managed to solve this, I'll update the answer.